# Control the way .NET BCL types are shown in the debugger (interested in KeyValuePair(TKey, TValue) )

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

There's a question here regarding the overriding of ToString() in KeyValuePair(TKey, TValue), which it's not possible.

I saw there are some attribute types like DebuggerDisplayAttribute, DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute which can control the way a type is displayed in the debugger. I only used debugger visualizers.

Logically, these attributes can only be applied to user-defined classes (except for partial classes I think).

So is there any way to control the debugging result of a built-in (BCL) .NET type in Visual Studio?

**EDIT**: To make it a little bit clearer, I'm mainly interested in the string representation of the type. It's sort of 'overriding' ToString() just for debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some time ago I wrote a post about [reading SQL exception dumps](http://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2012/06/16/read-last-executed-sql-statement-from-a-memory-dump/) where I used the visualizer for `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter`). You may read the whole post for a working example but in your case following steps are required:

In folder `C:\Users\<your login>\Documents\<your Visual Studio version>\Visualizers` there is a special file named `autoexp.cs` which stores your local visualizer settings (defined using `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`). If you can’t find this file you can safely copy it from `<Visual Studio installation folder>\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\Original\`. You can then append a new rule by the end of this file:

```
[assembly: DebuggerDisplay(@"\{MyKey = {Key}\}", Target = typeof(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<,>))]
```

Finally you need to recompile the file:

```
csc /t:library autoexp.cs
```

and restart Visual Studio. You new string representation of the KeyValuePair should appear in VS debugger.

Comment: In theory this should work like a charm, but I've tried it and it does't work. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 (I think I still have the Release Candidate version). I compiled it using the Native Tools Command Prompt, using the full path of the file (if I don't, it gives me file not found error). Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure that the autoexp.dll is located next to the autoexp.cs file in the `C:\Users\<your login>\Documents\<your Visual Studio version>\Visualizers` folder

Comment: It is, there is also a pair of autoexpce.cs / .dll and a attribcache90.bin. Even though the Documents folder is stored in D:\Documents, but I don't think it has something to do with that. When I compile the file it doesn't say nothing, no error and no output/message.

Comment: Just to make sure that it's not a problem with a user-documents folder, please move the autoexp.* files from it to `VisualStudioInstallPath\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers` (make backup of the replaced files first:) )

Comment: There were no such files in the specified folder, but I did it anyway, and still doesn't work. I tried to write some messy code in the .cs file and the compiler threw errors, so it works and it's aware of the file. Problem is the changes don't reflect in the debugger. I even tried to create a simple {test} rule for the String class and it didn't work. On a quick look, it seems like even default view rules don't work (took a quick test with the Type and Pen rules in the Immediate Window ad the debugger and it didn't match the one in the file)

Comment: The reason default rules didn't show was because I have a library assembly which referenced Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll but the console which I ran in debug mode didn't. Still, default rules apply, but I modified one of them and the result didn't show up. Not to mention that couldn't make KeyValuePair<,> work in any way

Comment: Hi @Tiby, I've just tested this solution on VS2012RC and it's working - I'm sorry but I have no idea why you can't get it running on your machine:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17569/discussion-between-tiby-and-lowleveldesign)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2005 and later have something called [Visualizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx). You could attempt to author your own.

Comment: I already wrote a visualizer for a type of mine. But is it possible to attach a visualizer to a .net type? And even if it was, visualizers are form based, and I was mainly interested in the string representation of the type.